# Spring Boot Rest JPA data not been post in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to post data to a database with Spring Boot REST API. I have two entities, User and roll. For roll, I have manually posted the data to the database, and when I'm trying to post data for user through Postman, only null is posted to the database.

user.java

```
package com.anurag.entities;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="uid")
    private int id;
    private String uName;
    private String uNickName;
    private String uEmail;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Roll roll;

}
```

roll.java

```
package com.anurag.entities;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Roll {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    @Column(name="rId")
    private int id;
    private String  roll;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="roll")
    private  List<User> user;

}
```

in database it shows like this

```
user database

uid u_email u_name u_nick_name roll_r_id
1     null  null     null         101


roll database(manually filled data)
r_id    roll
101     admin
102     employee
103    employeer
```

usercontroller.java

```
package com.anurag.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.anurag.entities.User;
import com.anurag.services.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
    
    //1. save all
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveAll(@RequestBody User user){
        Integer id = service.saveAll(user);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(id +"User is saved",HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

In Postman, I send data like this

```
{
    "uName" : "sabin",
    "uNickName" : "swa",
    "uEmail" : "aadi@gmail.com",
    "roll"   : {"id":101}
}
```

userservice.java

```
package com.anurag.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.anurag.Repository.UserRepository;
import com.anurag.entities.User;
import com.anurag.exception.UserNotFoundException;

@Service
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @Override
    public Integer saveAll(User user) {
     Integer id =   repo.save(user).getId(); 
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen in your logs if there isn't any errors?

Comment: yeah there is no error and roll id is inserted in database, if there was error roll id should not be inserted

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but do you mean _role_ instead of _roll_?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save user first and after find and set `Roll`

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<String> saveAll(@RequestBody User user, @RequestParam Ineger rollId){
    Integer id = service.saveAll(user, rollId);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(id +"User is saved",HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

in postman:

```
http://localhost:8080/save?rollId=<rollId>

{
    "uName" : "sabin",
    "uNickName" : "swa",
    "uEmail" : "aadi@gmail.com"
}
```

and service:

```
@Override
public Integer saveAll(User user, Integer rollId) {
    Roll roll = rollRepo.findById(rollId);
    user.setRoll(roll);
    Integer id = repo.save(user).getId(); 
    return id;
}
```

Better use `Integer` instead `int` for entity id field

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a join column for role in the User object. Please try with the below changes.

`@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id") private Roll roll;`